# Group multiple variables by multiple variables?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset with two categorical and two integer variables.

I want to group each integer variable by each categorical variable, and then find the means. The code below produces the right output, but uses a forloop and seems super clunky.

Is there are better way?

```
In [15]:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
raw_data = {
    'category1': ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue','Blue'],
    'category2': ['Car', 'Bike', 'Car', 'Bike', 'Car','Bike'],
    'integer1': list(np.random.randint(10, size=6)),
    'integer2': list(np.random.randint(10, size=6)),
    }
​
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

In [18]:

category = ['category1','category2']
integer = ['integer1','integer2']

output=[]
​
for i, column in enumerate(df[category]):
        numeric_mean_per_category = df[integer].groupby(df[column]).mean().to_dict()
        output.append(numeric_mean_per_category)

In [19]:

output

Out[19]:
[{'integer1': {'Blue': 3.6666666666666665, 'Red': 6.333333333333333},
  'integer2': {'Blue': 3.6666666666666665, 'Red': 4.333333333333333}},
 {'integer1': {'Bike': 6.333333333333333, 'Car': 3.6666666666666665},
  'integer2': {'Bike': 2.6666666666666665, 'Car': 5.333333333333333}}]
```

Comment: Was either answer not satisfactory? Still any open issues on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is a sequence of pivot tables?:

```
for col in category:
    print(df.pivot_table(columns=col, values=integer))

category1      Blue       Red
integer1   5.333333  5.666667
integer2   5.666667  4.666667
category2      Bike       Car
integer1   5.666667  5.333333
integer2   5.333333  5.000000
```

Comment: The only thing that worries me, seeing yours is that the mean values are different.

Comment: thats because the numbers are randomly generated ;)

Comment: lol i've edited your question to use a random seed so that the answers match up

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [DataFrame.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) function, then [Transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the DataFrame.

```
for cat in category:
    print(df.groupby(cat).mean().T)

category1  Blue  Red
integer1      2    5
integer2      2    2
category2      Bike       Car
integer1   4.666667  2.333333
integer2   1.666667  2.333333
```